# How to stay in fullscreen mode after clicking on rel="external" links?

Tags: facebook, jqtouch

I'm building a mobile web app that allow user to login through Facebook using openauth. There are no pop-up but Facebook will force you to go their page and redirect you back to the uri that you stated. Therefore, there are no ajax loading of the facebook mobile login page. That's why i put rel="external" at the anchor.

When I'm in the full screen mode, clicking on those links will automatically brings me to Safari. Thus leaving the full screen mode.

May I know is there anyway around this? or are there other method of logging into FB without redirecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a target="_webapp" href='http://www.cnn.com">Cnn</a>
```

Change **rel** to **target**. Mission accomplished.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but target is no longer valid markup in html5